# replaceString() function in C

Tags: c, string, replace

I am currently learning C with the book "Programming in C 3rd edition" by Stephen G. Kochan.

The exercise require that I make a function that replaces a character string inside a character string with another character string. So the function call

```
replaceString(text, "1", "one");
```

Will replace, if exist, "1" in the character string *text* with "one".

To fullfill this exercise, you need the functions **findString()**, **insertString()** and **removeString()**.

This is the findString() function

```
int findString (const char source[], const char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    bool foundit = false;

    for ( i = 0; source[i] != '\0' && !foundit; ++i )
    {
        foundit = true;

        for ( j = 0; s[j] != '\0' && foundit; ++j )
            if ( source[j + i] != s[j] || source[j + i] == '\0' )
                foundit = false;

        if (foundit)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

If *s[]* is inside the string *source[]*, it returns an integer equal to the starting point for *s[]* inside the string. If it do not find *s[]* it will return -1.

The insertString() function is as follows

```
void insertString (char source[], char s[], int index)
{
    int  stringLength (char string[]);
    int j, lenS, lenSource;

    lenSource = stringLength (source);
    lenS      = stringLength (s);

    if ( index > lenSource )
        return;

    for ( j = lenSource; j >= index; --j )
        source[lenS + j] = source[j];

    for ( j = 0; j < lenS; ++j )
        source[j + index] = s[j];
}
```

This function take three arguments i.e. *source[]*, *s[]* and *index[]*. *s[]* is the string that I would like to put into *source[]* and *index[]* is where it should start (e.g. insertString("The son", "per", 4) makes the source string to "The person").

The function includes another function called *stringLength()*, which purpose is the same at its name. This is *stringLength()*

```
int stringLength (char string[])
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( string[count] != '\0' )
        ++count;

    return count;
}
```

The *removeString()* takes three arguments i.e. *word*, *i* and *count*. The function removes a number of characters inside another character string. This function I have not yet been able to make.

Just to sum it up, my question is:

**How do i make the function replaceString(), which looks for a word in a character string, and if it is there, then it replaces it with another?**

This has really bugged me for some time, and I would really appreciate your help on this.

UPDATE

**This is the code I have made so far**

```
// replaceString() program

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int findString (char source[], char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    bool foundit = false;

    for ( i = 0; source[i] != '\0' && !foundit; ++i )
    {
        foundit = true;

        for ( j = 0; s[j] != '\0' && foundit; ++j )
            if ( source[j + i] != s[j] || source[j + i] == '\0' )
                foundit = false;

        if (foundit)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}

int stringLength (char string[])
{
    int count = 0;

    while ( string[count] != '\0' )
        ++count;

    return count;
}


void replaceString(char source[], char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int findString(char source[], char s[]);
    int stringLength(char string[]);
    int start;

    if ( findString(source, str1) == -1 )
        return;
    else
    {
        start = findString(source, str1);

        int lenSource = stringLength(source);
        int lenStr2   = stringLength(str2);
        int counter   = lenStr2;
        for ( lenSource; lenSource > start + lenStr2; --lenSource )
        {
            source[lenSource + lenStr2] = source[lenSource];
        }

        int i = 0;

        while ( i != counter )
        {
            source[start + i] = str2[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    void replaceString(char source[], char str1[], char str2[]);

    char string[] = "This is not a string";
    char s1[] = "not";
    char s2[] = "absolutely";

    printf ("Before: \n %s \n\n", string);

    replaceString(string, s1, s2);

    printf ("After: \n %s \n\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the following output:

Before:
 This is not a string

After:
 This is absolutelyng

As you can see, I have not included the removeString function(), as I could not get that function working properly. Where is the error in my program?

Comment: Why not show us what you have so far?

Comment: I have now uploaded what I have made so far.

Comment: Could you work out `removeString`? I had problems with that simple function when I changed it to search for the null character first (to make it less error-prone).

Answer (score 0):

for starters, your string's length is fixed.  so if the "destination" is longer than "source", then it won't work. insert string needs to pass in a pointer, then you can allocate a string on the heap that is long enough to contain length(source)-length(remove) +length(add), and return that pointer

Answer (score 0):

Say your `replaceString()` args are `(char source[], char s1[], char replacement[])`

You need to use `findString()` to find `s1` in source. If it finds it, given the position of `s1`, use `removeString()` to remove that string and then `insertString()` to insert `replacement` into that position.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie in programming. I came across this same exercise some days ago and just solved it today.
This is my code.

```
/* Programme to replace a string by using find, remove and insert
functions ex9.8.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 501

// Function prototypes
void read_Line (char buffer[]);
int string_Length (char string[]);
int find_String (char string1[], char string2[]);
void remove_String (char source[], int start, int number);
void insert_String (char source[], int start, char input[]);
void replace_String (char origString[], char targetString[], char substString[]);

bool foundFirstCharacter = false;

int main(void)
{
    printf("This is a programme to replace part of a string.\n");
    printf("It can only handle up to 500 characters in total!\n");

    char text[MAX];
    bool end_Of_Text = false;
    int textCount = 0;

    printf("\nType in your source text.\n");
    printf("When you are done, press 'RETURN or ENTER'.\n\n");

    while (! end_Of_Text)
    {
        read_Line(text);

        if (text[0] == '\0')
        {
            end_Of_Text = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textCount += string_Length(text);
        }
        break;
    }

    // Declare variables to store seek string parameters
    int seekCount = 0;
    char seekString[MAX];

    printf("\nType in the string you seek.\n");
    printf("When you are done, press 'RETURN or ENTER'.\n\n");

    while (! end_Of_Text)
    {
        read_Line(seekString);

        if (seekString[0] == '\0')
        {
            end_Of_Text = true;
        }
        else
        {
            seekCount += string_Length(seekString);
        }
        break;
    }

    // Declare variables to store replacement string parameters
    int replCount = 0;
    char replString[MAX];

    printf("\nType in the replacement string.\n");
    printf("When you are done, press 'RETURN or ENTER'.\n\n");

    while (! end_Of_Text)
    {
        read_Line(replString);

        if (replString[0] == '\0')
        {
            end_Of_Text = true;
        }
        else
        {
            replCount += string_Length(replString);
        }
        break;
    }

    // Call the function
    replace_String (text, seekString, replString);

    return 0;
}

// Function to get text input
void read_Line (char buffer[])
{
    char character;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        character = getchar();
        buffer[i] = character;
        ++i;
    }
    while (character != '\n');

    buffer[i - 1] = '\0';
}

// Function to determine the length of a string
int string_Length (char string[])
{
    int len = 0;

    while (string[len] != '\0')
    {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}

// Function to find index of sub-string
int find_String (char string1[], char string2[])
{
    int i, j, l;
    int start;
    int string_Length (char string[]);

    l = string_Length(string2);

    for (i = 0, j = 0; string1[i] != '\0' && string2[j] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (string1[i] == string2[j])
        {
            foundFirstCharacter = true;
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            j = 0;
        }
    }

    if (j == l)
    {
        start = i - j + 1;
        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        return j - 1;
    }
}

// Function to remove characters in string
void remove_String (char source[], int start, int number)
{
    int string_Length (char string[]);
    int i, j, l;
    char ch = 127;

    l = string_Length(source);
    j = start + number;

    for (i = start; i < j; ++i)
    {
        if (i >= l)
        {
            break;
        }
        source[i] = ch;
    }
    //printf("\nOutput: %s\n", source);
}

// Function to insert characters in string
void insert_String (char source[], int start, char input[])
{
    int string_Length (char string[]);
    int i, j, k, l, m;
    int srcLen;
    int inpLen;
    int totalLen;
    int endInsert;

    srcLen = string_Length(source);
    inpLen = string_Length(input);

    // Declare buffer array to hold combined strings
    totalLen = srcLen + inpLen + 3;
    char buffer[totalLen];

    // Copy from source to buffer up to insert position
    for (i = 0; i < start; ++i)
        buffer[i] = source[i];

    // Copy from input to buffer from insert position to end of input
    for (j = start, k = 0; k < inpLen; ++j, ++k)
        buffer[j] = input[k];

    endInsert = start + inpLen;

    for (m = start, l = endInsert; m <= srcLen, l < totalLen; ++m, ++l)
        buffer[l] = source[m];
    buffer[l] = '\0';

    printf("\nOutput: %s\n", buffer);
}

// Function to replace string
void replace_String (char origString[], char targetString[], char substString[])
{
    // Function prototypes to call
    void read_Line (char buffer[]);
    int string_Length (char string[]);
    int find_String (char string1[], char string2[]);
    void remove_String (char source[], int start, int number);
    void insert_String (char source[], int start, char input[]);

    // Search for target string in source text first
    int index;
    index = find_String (origString, targetString);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        printf("\nTarget string not in text. Replacement not possible!\n");
        exit(999);
    }

    // Remove found target string
    int lengthTarget;
    lengthTarget = string_Length(targetString);

    remove_String(origString, index - 1, lengthTarget);

    // Insert replacement string
    insert_String(origString, index, substString);
}
```